# Text change event on jquery template

Tags: jquery

I have Jquery-tmpl like this below

```
<script id="tmpl-gridDetail" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">   
        <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #99BCE8">
            <td>
                <a class="item-remove">remove</a>
            </td>   
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:yellow" class="cell-number" ><input type="text" class="cell-number pphClass" value="${PPH}"  /></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:yellow" class="cell-number pphPercentClass"><input type="text" class="cell-number pphPercentClass" value="${PPHPercent}"  /></td>
        </tr>   
    </script>
```

I want to make event text change when PPHPercent is changed. I add alert on this

```
      $("#gridDetailBody").find(".cell-number").click(function () {
            if (state != FormState.VIEW) {
                var txt = $(this).find("input[type='text']");
                if (txt.length == 0) {
                    $(this).html("<input type='text' style='width:100%' value='" + $(this).html().replace(/\./g, '') + "'/>");

                    $(this).find("input[type=text]").blur(function () {
                        var col = $(this).parent("td");
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        $(col).html((value));

                        //refresh total
                        var tr = $(col).parent("tr");
                        var cols = $(tr).children("td");

                        $('.pphPercentClass').live('change',function(){
                           alert('clicked in template');
                        });

                    }).focus();

                }
            }
        });
```

But it's not working.. even I change like this below also not working.

```
$(".pphPercentClass").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

Comment: change event on td element won't work. change event is for input elements only.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for it?

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal.. I change to input element already but still not firing.. I update my code